# TypeDescriptor.GetProperties() vs Type.GetProperties()

Tags: c#, reflection, types, typedescriptor

Consider the following code.

```
Object obj;
PropertyDescriptorCollection A = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj);
PropertyInfo[] B = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

I'm trying to understand the difference between A and B. From what I understand **TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()** will return custom **TypeDescriptor** properties, where as **Type.GetProperties()** will only return intrinsic "real" properties of the object. Is this right?  If obj doesn't have any custom **TypeDescriptor** properties then it just defaults to also returning the literal intrinsic properties of the object.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`obj.GetType().GetProperties()` does not return a `PropertyDescriptorCollection`, it returns a `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[]`. The `PropertyInfo` class does, as you suggest, represent only actual properties created on the object. A `PropertyDescriptor` is either a custom concrete child of the `PropertyDescriptor` class (implemented by the type defining the custom descriptor), or is an instance of the sealed internal class `ReflectPropertyDescriptor` that uses the `PropertyInfo` class to provide dynamic invocation of the property.

So for a class that does not define a custom descriptor, you will functionally get the same objects back, though the `PropertyDescriptor` is abstracting away the `PropertyInfo`.

Answer (score 10):

The `TypeDescriptor` class is used in designers, so that they can interact with the design-time environment. In particular, designers can override and extend various features of `TypeDescriptor`, but not `Type`.

One good example is working with data-bound controls. The `DataSource` property is of type `System.Object`, yet at design-time, that property is replaced with a new property that has a richer design-time UI.

Comment: It's used in designers, but it's also used for data binding, so it isn't just a design-time technology.

Answer (score 10):

The `TypeDescriptor` class returns `PropertyDescriptor` objects that represent the properties in the type of `obj` as well as any other properties that were contributed to the object itself or to its type.

The component model is actually quite complex, but as you describe, the basic implementation of `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()` will return [`ReflectPropertyDescriptor`](http://typedescriptor.net/System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor?clr=Net_4.0) instances that represent an indirection to typical `PropertyInfo` objects.  You can use `PropertyDescriptor` objects very much like `PropertyInfo` objects: they can be used to get and set the value of the property and they have attributes.

For `DependencyObject` instances in WPF, `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()` also returns attached properties.  These `PropertyDescriptor` objects in this case provide an indirection to the dependency object model rather than to reflection.

In the component designer, it is possible to use `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute` (and maybe some other techniques) to create your own `PropertyDescriptor` objects at runtime or at designtime.  In any case, it is possible that the properties returned from `Type.GetProperties()` may very well differ from those returned from `TypeDescriptor`, depending on the context.