# C#: What's the Difference Between TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes() and GetType() .GetCustomAttributes?

Tags: c#, attributes, typedescriptor

Take these two code things:

```
instance.GetType()
 .GetCustomAttributes(true)
 .Where(item => item is ValidationAttribute);
```

And

```
TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(instance)
 .OfType<ValidationAttribute>();
```

If the class looks like:

```
[RequiredIfOtherPropertyIsNotEmpty("State", "City", ErrorMessage = ErrorDescription.CreateAccount_CityRequiredWithState)]
[RequiredIfOtherPropertyIsNotEmpty("State", "Address1", ErrorMessage = ErrorDescription.CreateAccount_Address1RequiredWithState)]
public class ManagePostModel
{
   ...
}
```

Where `RequiredIfOtherPropertyIsNotEmpty` is a `ValidationAttribute` and has `AllowMultiple = true`.

The first one returns two attributes, the second returns one.

What's the difference that would cause this?

Comment: See also [typedescriptor-getproperties-vs-type-getproperties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402239/typedescriptor-getproperties-vs-type-getproperties)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the MSDN page on TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edecex5w(VS.80).aspx):

> In order to return multiple instances of an `AttributeUsageAttribute.AllowMultiple` attribute from the `AttributeCollection`, your attribute must override the `Attribute.TypeId` property.

To answer the general question "what's the difference?": the values returned by `TypeDescriptor` can be extended at runtime, whereas those in `Type` cannot. The MSDN page I linked to explains more.

If you don't need this kind of runtime extension, and the way `TypeDescriptor` handles multiple attributes is a problem, you're probably better off with `Type.GetCustomAttributes`.

Comment: So Type.GetCustomAttributes cannot get attributes that are added at runtime (i mean attributes added by using TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(...) ) right ?

Comment: `TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(...)` is not not available for at least `netstandard1.3` and `netstandard1.4`