# Reflection Type vs TypeDescriptor

Tags: c#, reflection, typedescriptor

Lately I have been using reflection to work in my project, and I have the current question.

While in `Type.GetProperties(Flags)`, we can filter the properties we get using 'Flags'; in `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()`, we don't.

In `type.GetProperties` I can filter to get only properties **not inherited**.
Is it possible to do the same with `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()` (only properties not inherited)?

Thank you

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402239/typedescriptor-getproperties-vs-type-getproperties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't.

The `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()` is used to get `PropertyDescriptor` instances with possibility to filter using specific `Attribute`s.

The `Type.GetProperties()` is used to get `PropertyInfo` instances with possibility to filter using specific `BindingFlags`.