# TypeDescriptor.GetProperties vs. Type.GetProperties

Tags: c#, reflection, typedescriptor

I'm looking at some code where an MSDN  author uses the following in different methods of the same class:

```
if ( TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(ModelInstance)[propertyName] != null ) return;

var property = ModelInstance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
```

Would you use the former because its faster and you only need to query a property and the latter if you need to manipulate it? Something else?

Comment: I would use the one that makes the most sense in your application and is the most readable to you, and profile it for performance later.

Comment: Possibly the author was trying to show an example of each API.

Comment: They both seem readable enough but I couldn't say if one made more sense than another without understanding the difference(s). I thought that was implicit in the question but maybe not...

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeDescriptor.GetProperties() vs Type.GetProperties()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402239/typedescriptor-getproperties-vs-type-getproperties)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first method should generally not be faster since internally per default it actually uses the second method. The TypeDescriptor architecture adds functionality on top of the normal reflection (which `instance.GetType().GetProperty(...)` represents. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx for more information about the TypeDescriptor architecture.

In general using reflection directly is faster (i.e. your second line above), but there may be a reason for using the TypeDescriptor if some custom type provider is in use which may return other results than the standard reflection.

Comment: For the OP's benefit: the classic example here is DataTable/DataView. The *reflection* properties are things like `.Columns`, `.Rows` etc. However the *descriptor* properties are **the columns defined in the table**. this is (sort-of... some white-lies here involving `ITypedList`) how data-binding to a table shows the data columns.