# logging all properties of an object in c#. how to log inner object properties as well?

Tags: c#, properties, inner-classes

i am trying to (1) log all properties of an object, and (2) all properties of a specific object type within. i can do the (1) but not (2).

this is the case now.

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(object1))
{
     string name = descriptor.Name;
     object value = descriptor.GetValue(object1);
     logger.Debug(String.Format("{0} = {1}", name, value));
}
```

what i need is something like:

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(object1))
{
     string name = descriptor.Name;
     object value = descriptor.GetValue(object1);
     logger.Debug(String.Format("{0} = {1}", name, value));

     // TODO check if the current property of object1 is of type object2, how?
     if (...) {
     // TODO repeat the process for object2

     foreach (PropertyDescriptor innerdescriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(object2))
     {
          string innername = innerdescriptor.Name;
          object innervalue = innerdescriptor.GetValue(object2);
          logger.Debug(String.Format("     {0} = {1}", innername, innervalue));
     }

     } // end if
}
```

however, this second thing doesn't work no matter what i try. so, please help.

**update**
i have an answer (by @Alex Art.) to the check

```
if (descriptor.PropertyType == typeof(the type that you expecting) )  { ... }
```

*now the only thing that remains is the inner object properties logger!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be achieved by using reflection (But you should be aware of performance penalty):

```
public void LogProps(Object object1)
{
   var objType = object1.GetType();

   IList<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>(objType.GetProperties());

   foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
   {
       var propValue = prop.GetValue(object1, null);
       if(prop.PropertyType == typeof(yourTypeHere))
       {  
          LogProps(propValue);
       }
       else
       {           
           logger.Debug(String.Format("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, propValue));
       }
   }
}
```

*I also used a recursion here which is also could be problematic if you have some long hierarchy*

**Regarding your solution:**

> // TODO check if the current property of object1 is of type object2,
>   how?

Did you try using [PropertyDescriptor.PropertyType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx)?:

```
 object value = descriptor.GetValue(object1);

 if (descriptor.PropertyType == typeof(the type that you expecting) ) 
 {

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor innerdescriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value) 
    {
         string innername = innerdescriptor.Name;
         object innervalue = innerdescriptor.GetValue(object2);
         logger.Debug(String.Format("     {0} = {1}", innername, innervalue));
    }

 } // end if
```

Comment: so, is that a no on my idea? is it not possible? i really like my foreach (PropertyDescriptor... since the performance is an issue here ;)

Comment: yep. that IF works. thnx <3 will update the question.

Comment: By the way i just figured out that TypeDescriptor is built on top of reflection engine(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx) so there is no any gain in performance when you use it :-)

Comment: Some even say that pure reflection is faster (which makes sence) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573913/typedescriptor-getproperties-vs-type-getproperties

Answer (score 1):

If this is for the purpose of logging the state of the object at runtime, you'll probably find it easier to [serialize the whole object as JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and store that instead.  This has the added benefit of being human readable and more flexible than a custom solution.

To ignore certain properties, apply the IgnoreDataMemberAttribute to them.

i.e.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObjectParent
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ImportantValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public MyObjectChild Child { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public AnotherClassThatIWantToIgnore IgnoreMe { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyObjectChild
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ImportantValue { get; set; }   
}

public string ObjectAsJson<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
       serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
       return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: i would use it, but i get this error (due to datetime.min use): DateTime values that are greater than DateTime.MaxValue or smaller than DateTime.MinValue when converted to UTC cannot be serialized to JSON. also i do not have access to the object, so cannot change it with annotations.