# How to log object properties in SenseTalk

Tags: eggplant

What's the easiest way to log all the properties of an object in SenseTalk?

Like this [C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330935/logging-all-properties-of-an-object-in-c-how-to-log-inner-object-properties-as) but for eggplant scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sense talk [objects are represented as propertyLists](http://docs.eggplantsoftware.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-objects.htm). You can iterate over the keys of an object using the exact [same syntax as you would with a propertyList](http://docs.eggplantsoftware.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-property-lists.htm#iterating-over).

```
set mike to {current:["Mike and the Mechanics","Genesis"],previous:"Red 7"}

repeat with each item of keys(mike)
  put it & ": " & property (it) of mike
end repeat

// current: [Mike and the Mechanics,Genesis]
// previous: Red 7
```